# How to access variables in a list / object in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

In Terraform, how can access the values from the variable below?

```
variable "egress_rules" {
  type = list(object({
    from_port = number
    to_port = number
    protocol = string
    cidr_blocks = list(string)
  }))
  default = [
    {
      from_port = 0
      to_port = 0
      protocol = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "egress" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.new.id
  type = "ingress"
  for_each = var.egress_rules
    from_port   = each.value.from_port
    to_port     = each.value.to_port
    protocol    = each.value.protocol
    cidr_blocks = each.value.cidr_blocks
}
```

But got this error:

```
Error: Invalid for_each argument
```

What is the correct way to reference this variable?

Comment: For `for_each` uses `ingress_rules`, but your variable is `egress_rules`?

Comment: My bad @Marcin I copied the wrong example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/meta-arguments/for_each.html) will not work with a list of maps. You have to convert it to a map. This is commonly done through a [for expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/for.html):

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "egress" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.new.id
  type = "ingress"
  for_each = { for idx, rule in var.egress_rules: idx => rule }
    from_port   = each.value.from_port
    to_port     = each.value.to_port
    protocol    = each.value.protocol
    cidr_blocks = each.value.cidr_blocks
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Adding to above answer from** @Marcin

If you want to use single object instead of list then you can directly access without for_each

Instead of declaring it as list of objects; use single object as shown below

```
variable "egress_rules" {
  type = object({
    from_port = number
    to_port = number
    protocol = string
    cidr_blocks = list(string)
  })
  default = ({
      from_port = 0
      to_port = 0
      protocol = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }}
}
```

Then access in your resource like

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "egress" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.new.id
  from_port   = var.egress_rules.from_port
  to_port     = var.egress_rules.from_port
  protocol    = var.egress_rules.protocol
  cidr_blocks = var.egress_rules.cidr_blocks
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to set multiple properties of a resource you could use a map of objects like this:

```
variable "egress_rules" {
  type = map(object({
    from_port = number
    to_port = number
    protocol = string
    cidr_blocks = list(string)
  }))
}
```

Your variable definition would be:

```
egress_rules = {
    {
      from_port = 0
      to_port = 0
      protocol = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
}
```

The updated resource definition would be:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "egress" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.new.id
  type = "egress"
  for_each = var.egress_rules
    from_port   = each.value["from_port"]
    to_port     = each.value["to_port"]
    protocol    = each.valuep["protocol"]
    cidr_blocks = each.value["cidr_blocks"]
}
```

Comment: Your example of egress_rules does not match its type. Also what is `ingress_rules` if you define `egress_rules`? Also there is a spelling mistake in `valuep`?

Comment: This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint: map
of object required.